# Many-to-Many query using SQL

Tags: sql, many-to-many

EmployeeGroups have many MedicalPlans. MedicalPlans have many EmployeeGroups (many-to-many relationship). They are connected though the EmployeeBenefits join table

```
EmployeeGroup
:id
:name

MedicalPlan
:id
:name

EmployeeBenefits
:id
:employee_group_id
:medical_plan_id
```

Does anyone know a query I can use to retrieve all the EmployeeGroups who have a certain MedicalPlan?

I don't believe INNER JOIN works here because they do not have a atribute in common. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't join either. Sounds more like an `EXISTS` query: Get all employee groups for which **exists** a certain medical plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, inner join works

```
select eg.name
from EmployeeGroup eg
join EmployeeBenefits eb on eb.employee_group_id = eg.id
join MedicalPlan mp on eb.medical_plan_id = mp.id
where mp.name = 'my plan'
```

Comment: Ahhh, never thought of the double inner join. Thanks! This is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXISTS` or `IN` for such tasks:

```
select *
from employeegroup
where id in
(
  select employee_group_id
  from employeebenefits
  where medical_plan_id = (select id from medicalplan where name = 'XYZ')
);
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten! Never used EXISTS or IN before (really new to SQL). Appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. `EXISTS` and `IN` are very useful to get queries readable, and they put criteria where it belongs: in the WHERE clause.